# Recursive SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, recursion

I have a bit of a messy dataset and I am needing to get all child accounts for a particular parent account.

The table is as follows

> Code (PK),  Name, ParentCode

There are no foreign keys

From what I can see if an account does not have a parent, the ParentCode is an empty string or it is set to be the same as the Code.

I have been trying to follow http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx but it seems to be returning all the data, plus I cannot work out how I can get the children for just one account.

```
WITH DirectReports (ParentCus, Code, Name, Level)
AS
(
    SELECT ParentCode, Code, Name, 0 AS Level
    FROM Customers
      WHERE Code = ParentCode OR Code = ''
    UNION ALL

    SELECT c.ParentCode, c.Code, c.Name, level + 1
    FROM Customers AS C
    INNER JOIN DirectReports AS d
        ON c.ParentCode = d.Code
        where c.Code != d.Code
)
SELECT ParentCus, Code, Name, Level
FROM DirectReports
```

***EDIT***
To be clear I need to be able pass my function a Code and return all (recursively) that's accounts child accounts.

***Final Code***
I had to make a slight change to the answer but here is the final working code

```
declare @t table(code varchar(10), name varchar(10), parentcode varchar(10))
insert @t values(1, 'navn1', '1')
insert @t values(2, 'navn2', '')
insert @t values(3, 'navn3', 1)
insert @t values(4, 'navn4', 3)
insert @t values(5, 'navn5',4)
insert @t values(6, 'navn6', 2)
insert @t values(7, 'navn7', 3)

declare @code varchar(10) -- or however code/parentcode is declared
set @code = '1'           -- the parentcode you are trying to isolate

;WITH DirectReports (ParentCus, Code, Name, Level)
AS
(
    SELECT ParentCode, Code, Name, 0 AS Level
    FROM @t Customers
    -- this picks the chosen code
      WHERE Code = @code and (Code = ParentCode OR PARENTCode = '')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.ParentCode, c.Code, c.Name, level + 1
    FROM
        (select * from @t where  code !=  parentcode) --had to do this to account for an infinate loop
        as C
    INNER JOIN DirectReports AS d
        ON c.ParentCode = d.Code

)
SELECT ParentCus, Code, Name, Level
FROM DirectReports
-- level > 0: to ensure child accounts only
where level > 0
```

Comment: Do you need children by parentid? Write clearly what is the data you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify which code you want.
This example is using @t to replace your table Customers

```
declare @t table(code varchar(10), name varchar(10), parentcode varchar(10))
insert @t values(1, 'navn1', '')
insert @t values(2, 'navn2', '')
insert @t values(3, 'navn3', 1)

declare @code varchar(10) -- or however code/parentcode is declared
set @code = '1'           -- the parentcode you are trying to isolate

;WITH DirectReports (ParentCus, Code, Name, Level)
AS
(
    SELECT ParentCode, Code, Name, 0 AS Level
    FROM @t Customers
    -- this picks the chosen code
      WHERE Code = @code and (Code = ParentCode OR PARENTCode = '')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.ParentCode, c.Code, c.Name, level + 1
    FROM @t C
    INNER JOIN DirectReports AS d
        ON c.ParentCode = d.Code
    -- added to prevent infinite loop, 
    -- I should point out that when this happens, you have bad data in your base
    WHERE c.ParentCode <> c.Code
)
SELECT ParentCus, Code, Name, Level
FROM DirectReports
-- level > 0: to ensure child accounts only
-- level < 100:to prevent infinite loops caused by circular references
where level > 0 and level < 100
```

Comment: Had to make a slight change (See edit) but this did it. Thanks!

Comment: @tyrongower sounds like you have bad data, I wrote another way for you to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

```
;With CTE as 
(
select ParentCode, Code, Name,row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as rn from Customers
)

,DirectReports as (ParentCus, Code, Name, Level)
AS
(
    SELECT rn,ParentCode, Code, Name, 0 AS Level
    FROM CTE WHERE rn=1 and (Code = ParentCode OR Code = '')
    UNION ALL

    SELECT c.ParentCode, c.Code, c.Name, level + 1
    FROM CTE AS C
    INNER JOIN DirectReports AS d
        ON c.ParentCode = d.Code and c.rn=d.rn+1
        where c.Code != d.Code
)
SELECT ParentCus, Code, Name, Level
FROM DirectReports
```